# Как изменить текст textView из другого класса?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть два класса, один класс `MainActivity`, а другой собственный класс. Мой активити класс содержит `textView`. Как я могу изменить текст `textView` из своего класса?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {        

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView t = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        t.setText("Текст");
    }         
}

class Helper
{
    public void run()
    {
        TextView text = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        text.setText("Второй текст");
    }
}
```

Исходя из ответов, я решил дописать код с некоторыми правками. Теперь создается объект класса `Helper`, который принимает текущее активити. При этом класс `Helper` наследуется от класса `TimerTask`, который уже не содержит в себе метода `findViewById` и соответственно выдает ошибку `'Cannot resolve method'`. Как можно обойти этот момент?

При попытке передачи активити в класс `Helper`, код выполняется, но приложение моментально вылетает при попытке записать текст в поле `textView2`.

Пример обновленного кода:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextView t;
    public  TextView text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        t.setText("Текст");

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new Helper(MainActivity.this);

        timer.schedule(task, 2000, 5000);
    }
}

class Helper extends TimerTask
{
    private MainActivity activity;
    public Helper(MainActivity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    public static int i = 0;
    public void run()
    {
        TextView text = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        text.setText("Второй текст" + ++i);
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас подход неправильный. не нужно тащить активность в класс, нужно подать ей сигнал чтобы она обновилась сама. Я могу продемонстрировать при желании

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант - во время создания Helper отдавать ему вашу активити или сразу TextView. Не забывайте учитывать что при пересоздании активити(например, поворот экрана) и активити, и textView надо указывать новые

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {        
    public TextView t, textView2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        t.setText("Текст");
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }         
}

class Helper
{
    private MainActivity activity;
    public Helper(MainActivity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        TextView text = activity.textView2;
        text.setText("Второй текст");
    }
}
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку 'Cannot resolve method' и приложение все равно продолжает падать , при попытке записать текст в textView2. Обновил пример, чтобы было проще понять

Comment: так какой метод-то не может найти? Почти уверен, что метод run, потому что не поставили аннотацию @Override  над его описанием

Comment: Метод findViewById, так как он существует только в классе AppCompatActivity, от которого Helper не наследуется

Comment: Так поэтому активность и передана сюда ссылкой - у неё и вызывайте: `activity.findViewById(R.id.textView2);`. Но с учётом того, что у вас это `TimerTask` вставить текст здесь не получится - нельзя менять UI не из UI-потока. Нужно заворачивать в `Runnable` и постить в UI-поток через `Handler`, `View.post()` или `Activity.runOnUiThread()`. Кстати `Timer` и `TimerTask` в Андроид использовать не рекомендуется - они добавлены в SDK только ради совместимости с существующим java-кодом

Comment: Да. не указал что findViewByActivity надо вызывать от activity. А вообще лучше findViewById вынести в onCreate, а в таске обращаться к полю активити. Или вообще активити не передавать в таск, достаточно передать textView. А еще лучше - не использовать таски. Не легко придумать ситуацию в которой нужна просто отсрочка действия. Обычно она нужна либо по окончании какого-то процесса или по расписанию. И там и там таймер так себе решение, как верно заметил комментатор выше

Answer (score -2):

Может быть так ?

```
class Helper {
    public void run() {
    MainActivity.text.setText("Второй текст");
    }
}
```

Но возможно придётся добавить видимость для "text".

Comment: нет, так делать нельзя. нужно в классе Helper создать интерфейс обратного вызова (колбэк), который будет содержать данные, которые необходимо передать и имплементировать его в активити.

Comment: Для интереса, проверил свой пример - работает. Но, AS подсказала, что поле TextView должно быть объявлено как static. Не могли бы вы пояснить, чем ваш вариант лучше ?

Comment: @cc08, а теперь AS вам разве не подсказывает, что это самое поле приведёт к утечке памяти (то есть удержанию в памяти экземпляра активити когда она будет закрыта и уже не нужна)?

Comment: @woesss, активити, как я понял из наименования, является главным в приложении. То есть, закрытие этого активити, приведет к закрытию всего приложения. И вы хотите сказать, что статик переменная останется в памяти после закрытия приложения ???

Comment: Главным является процесс (в понятиях ОС), процесс запускает ВМ, а она уже приложение. Главным классом в приложении является `Application` - он создаётся первым и существует пока существует ВМ. И статические поля существуют и хранят значения пока живёт ВМ. От активностей их время жизни зависит, конечно, но только в том смысле, что пока одна из них находится на переднем плане весь процесс (а следовательно и ВМ) не могут быть уничтожены. А при переходе активности в бэкграунд процесс ставится в "расстрельную" очередь. Но когда его толкнут к стенке зависит наличия свободных ресурсов.